# Weird pagespeed URL for PNG image?

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing, pagespeed

I uploaded a PNG image with alpha transparency to my server with the filename logo.png, however, when the image is used on a page and I go to see it's file-path, I get:

```
http://example.com/i/300x300xlogo.png.pagespeed.ic.0A66xVq4G9.png
```

That file is nowhere to be seen on the server.

I don't know if it affects it, but the actual image size is 400px by 400px, and I have it displayed in the HTML as 300px by 300px. (Don't ask.)

Could it be my web-host doing this? Seems to prefix the file with the resolution to be displayed at: `300x300x` and also has that weird suffix: `.pagespeed.ic.0A66xVq4G9.png`

Comment: Without something to look at (and ponder), it could be conjecture. My guess is, load balanced Wifi connection with a heavy-handed source-manipulating setup. AT&T in the US is good for this kind of "speed enhancement" strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you're seeing is as intended: mod_pagespeed rewrites the image URL to an optimized name and embeds the size, as well as the fingerprint of the content into the filename.

If you're downscaling the image in HTML from the original size.. you're wasting user's bandwidth, which is especially painful on mobile. Advantage of mod_pagespeed is that it can do this resizing for you on the fly - simply specify the desired dimensions in the HTML and it will do the right thing.

You can read more about the various image optimizations done by mod_pagespeed here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-image-optimize

What you're describing as "loading slower" sounds like "image lazyload":
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-lazyload-images

The images are deferred until onload fires, which helps get the page painted faster to the screen. You can also configure mod_pagespeed to do this on-scroll, such that only visible images are loaded. Finally, you can also disable this specific filter, but keep the image optimization done above.

P.S. mod_pagespeed is no longer beta, the team recently shipped 1.0.

Comment: Thank you, perfect! The image is a different size (only slightly larger) due to a responsive layout — what does Pagespeed do in that regard?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good solution for multiple-res images for responsive layouts at this point, and this is not comment for mod_pagespeed.. rather, a general statement.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, if the image is rendered at the size defined in the HTML, then it will be blurry if the browser window is adjusted and the image needs to be larger. It'll basically be stretched. (Or if mobile view goes from portrait to landscape.) Which is a problem :(

Comment: Are you dynamically removing the width and height attributes from your image tag when the orientation changes? If not, the image will still be same size, regardless of orientation. You can use CSS media queries to substitute different image sizes to address this.

Comment: Seems I had forgotten to add width & height to HTML image tag — rookie mistake. (Yup, changing size with media queries — so no compatibility issues with that?)

Answer (score 2):

Solved! [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) was enabled by default in the webhosts control panel. Hopefully this will help anyone else.

I noticed that images would actually load slower, they would flash once the document finished loading. (Google Pagespeed is beta though.)

Comment: Thanks for that! I had the same issue.