# Pagespeed resized images low quality

Tags: image, optimization, nginx, pagespeed

I don't understand why Google Pagespeed reduces the quality of my image after resizing process:

This is the original image:
http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/images/stories/2014/smart-for-city-a.jpg

And this is the resized:
http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/images/stories/2014/480x248xsmart-for-city-a.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Yfy3eHlQsi.jpg

I need that resized images preserve the full quality, without any loss.
How I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to say I cannot see the diff in your 2 photos either.
That said, I think the setting you're after is:

```
ModPagespeedImageRecompressionQuality -1
```

See: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize#recompressionquality

This keeps all the image_rewrite filters working, but enables lossless compression when recompressing images.

Answer (score 2):

mod_pagespeed should only resizes images if you have set explicit `width` and `height` attributes in your HTML and the `resize_images` filter is enabled. Is this image being resized to the wrong size for your site? Or do you have explicit `width` and `height` attributes, but still want the image at full size for some reason (ex: Retina display, zoom)?

You can turn this mod_pagespeed feature off with:

```
pagespeed DisableFilter resize_images;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify the width and height attributes in your image tag. This might solve the image resizing by Google's Pagespeed.

It seems that Google Pagespeed sometimes resizes images (and not only compresses them).
You can read more here:
[Weird pagespeed URL for PNG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113383/weird-pagespeed-url-for-png-image)

If you really want to delve deeper into the different attributes regarding Pagespeed image compression you can read more in the Google Pagespeed docs:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize

Hope this solves your problem,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should just modify which filters are enabled. Look here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize.

You're probably using `pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_images;` to optimize the images. Don't. (If you're not, then I'll change my answer).

`rewrite_images` is an alias for `inline_images,recompress_images,convert_png_to_jpeg,resize_images`, so just enable the ones you need:

`pagespeed EnableFilters inline_images,resize_images`

If you're not using nginx, then just use the appropriate Apache syntax or the correct filters if you're using the Pagespeed cdn service.

---

I honestly don't see a difference on my screen (not using a retina display). So Google might not be serving the right image in that it isn't respecting the difference for retina.

Look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-retinafy-your-websites--net-31793

Looking at how the PageSpeed service (the scoring one not the module / cdn) scores things helps explain the logic behind the module / cdn because the latter follows the evaluative logic of the former.

[Fix Google PageSpeed's "Serve scaled images" for responsive layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133562/fix-google-pagespeeds-serve-scaled-images-for-responsive-layout)

A quick jab via Twitter: https://twitter.com/hkfoster/status/303480645785624578

Basically: if the problem is with retina screens, then you should just turn off the `resize_images` filter.

Comment: I use rewrite_images yes. I disabled recompress_images (I think I can leave convert_png_to_jpg because I have not PNGs) but the quality of the resized images is the same

Comment: Why not just turn resize_images off then? Pagespeed really is a shortcut to correct not-so-optimal coding practices and server configurations. For instance, spriting is a total pain, but Google will do it for you. The extra speed that pagespeed gives you for resizing images is too much of a trade-off in this case. If you want the images resized, then you could just do it yourself. If the images need to be dynamically resized (user-uploaded content), then you can do so with GD or imagemagick..

Comment: I updated the answer a bit to reflect some of the above in the comment in relation to retina screens, which, as far as I can speculate, seems to be the problem.